# universal application weight

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios-universal-app

I developed my app for Ipad, now I should adapt it for Iphone. My app is quite heavy with a lot of images that should be available offline. These images are located in `xib` files and are sometimes loaded dynamically from app bundle. I need to limit the size of my app.

1. should I make a universal app or two different apps (each one with its own set of images optimized for the device)?
2. If I do a single universal app can I dynamically resize my "dynamically loaded images" in code. what should I do for the images in `xibs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer, one app with different xib sharing the same view controllers.
To limit the weight :

- Some images must be modified (eg: backgrounds) because they need to
  be adapted to the iphone screen resolution. I just named them
  image~iphone.png. The cool thing is that you dont need to modify
  images'name in xib or code because the ~iphone signifies image for
  the iphone.
- Some others can remain the same (eg: buttons) and I'll just size them
  down in the IB.